# Imageview won't show image with piccsso if the image is in HTTP format

Tags: android, http, https

I am using Picasso to inflate image from URL to Imageview:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HeroesViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Hero currentHero = heroList.get(position);
        String str = String.join(",", currentHero.abilities);

        holder.heroTitle.setText(currentHero.title);
        holder.heroAbilities.setText(str);
        Picasso.get().load(currentHero.image).resize(500, 500).into(holder.heroesImage);

    }
```

The thing is that everything that is HTTP protocol won't show up at emulator & physical device, only the ones that are HTTPS. Instead of showing it, it just leaves a black space.

The images that are HTTP protocol are also .png extension, if that has anything to do with that.

how can I workaround this issue?

Comment: What is image url?

Comment: https://heroapps.co.il/employee-tests/android/androidexam.json


this is the API containing all URLS - as you can see some are http and others are https

Comment: try without resizing it..

Comment: Maybe you need to allow cleartext to your manifest since you're accessing HTTP.     <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >
</application>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600 try this solution

Comment: without resizing still does not work and I have tried this stuff of cleartext and does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
Picasso.with(this)  // Activity context
       .load(currentHero.image) // Set URL
       .resize(100,100) // Resize the image
       .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_defuser)) // Default Image
       .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_defuser))
       .into(holder.heroesImage); // Imageview
```

Comment: Thank you! worked. I really have no idea what was the thing missing actually, maybe the placeholder?

Comment: Picasso.with is deprecated you should use Picasso.get

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
     .load(img_url)
     .resize(5,5)
     .fit().centerCrop().into(methodImage);
```